# Samba SWAT doesn't support include statement

Tags: samba

When I use Samba SWAT to change the smb.conf setting, I can't find include statement.

I then try manually change smb.conf:

```
[test]
  path = /mnt/test
  available = no
  include = /etc/samba/smb.%G.conf
```

Assume the group is "users", the /etc/samba/smb.users.conf contain:

```
  available = yes
```

The samba share "test" works as expected.  I then login to SWAT but I can't find include statement setting.  Making changes in SWAT will remove my include statement.

I am using samba 3.5.8-75 in Fedora Core 13.